# PHP reference Class from variable with static method access

Tags: php, class, static

**Gives an Error:**

```
$this->model::byUserPermission()

Leads to: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)
```

**Works:**

```
$facade = $this->model;
$facade::byUserPermission()
```

Is this a PHP Bug? Or can someone explain this to my, why that is happening (I am using php 5.6 and i am new to php. From my point of view, both are exactly the same). Thanks

Comment: Interesting. Maybe `::` has a higher precedence than `->`, in which case the code will be executed as `$this->(model::byUserPermission())`, which would be invalid, since calling a method on an undeclared constant doesn't make much sense. Can you try executing `($this->model)::byUserPermission()`? I'd think that would evaluate things in the right order.

Comment: thanks for your help! however thats something I tested before posting and this gives the same error as above... and ($facade)::byUserPermission gives an error too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this statement `$this->model::byUserPermission()` is ambiguous.  And can be interpreted in multiple ways.

1) You could be trying to use the `model` property of the class that you are in to call a class's static method.  As you are attempting in your question.

2) You could also mean you want to access the property of the class returned by the static function `byUserPermission()` in the `model` class.